# Storing Object Types in Variable then Initializing

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, pointers

Is there a way in Objective-C to store an object/class in a variable to be passed to alloc/init somewhere else?

For example:

```
UIViewController = foo
foo *bar = [[foo alloc] init]
```

I'm trying to create a system to dynamically create navigation buttons in a separate class based on the current view controller. I can pass 'self' to the method, but the variable that results does not allow me to alloc/init. I could always import the .h file directly, but ideally I would like to make reusing the code as simple as possible. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand your question, but if you are trying to create a fresh instance of the same class as another instance, you can do something like that:

```
id foo; // an actual instance of any class

id bar = [[[foo class] alloc] init]; // another instance
```

If foo isn't declared as `id`, you can even use a shortcut: `[[foo.class alloc] init]` or even shorter: `[foo.class new]`.

You can also use either the class object:

```
id foo;
Class fooClass = [foo class];

id bar = [[fooClass alloc] init];
```

Or the class name:

```
id foo;
NSString* fooClassName = NSStringFromClass( [foo class] );

id bar = [[NSClassFromString( fooClassName ) alloc] init];
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, chuck also had a similar response, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you store the className you would like to create as an `NSString`

You can try:
`id bar = [[NSClassFromString(foo) alloc] init]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just make the variable of type `Class`. To assign a named class to it, you can do it like this:

```
Class foo = [UIViewController class];
```

Or if the class name is a dynamically selected string (hey, it happens), you would do it like this:

```
NSString *className = @"UIViewController";
Class foo = NSClassFromString(className);
```